# refresh the ImageView in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView`, which display pictures from Internet, in `Adapter's` `getView` method, I will start the `Async` download thread to download the picture,since I don't know the exact time of downloading finished. As you know, when user touch the screen, the `ListView` will refresh itself and call `Adapter's` `getView` method, then the `ListView` has been refreshed. But if the user does not touch the screen, even the picture already been downloaded, the `ImageView` still  shows nothing.

So, my question is, what is the graceful way to refresh the `ListView` after downloading has finished?

Comment: An Incredibly detailed explanation and implementation can be found [here](http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/loading-remote-images-in-a-listview-on-android/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` to refresh the underlying views.

Comment: My last solution: I pass the adapter to the asyncTask and call notifydataSetChanged() in asyncTask's onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the image in the image view in a separate thread. Thus image will be loaded without touching it.